# gitlab-ci.yml add develop config angular

Tags: angular, continuous-integration, gitlab, devops

I make some commands for production,
I have two branch, master and develop, 
master have it's domain - site.com and develop - develop.site.com

so, when i will be on develop branch and will push i want to update develop.site.com
i have to make to make two gitlab-ce.yml file ? for master project and develop project?

it's my yml file now

```
image: node:12.13.0-alpine
before_script:
  - npm i -g firebase-tools
build:
  stage: build
  only: 
   - master
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm install --quiet
    - npm run build --prod
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/


deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  environment: 
    name: production
    url: $FIREBASE_URL
  only: 
   - master
  dependencies:
    - build
  cache:
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm run deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

No, in your case you just need to use only/except in our pipeline steps
Look at the documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic

You will create all the steps in the same gitlab-ci file but in each one you will set when the step will run

Another approach is to set the steps to `manual` (same doc above) and you will be able to trigger the steps manually